Apache2 gives 403 when serving websites outside /var/www/
Why does Apache2 give 403 when serving websites outside /var/www/?
I have the following configurations on my local machine for development and they worked perfectly fine before in my old machine.
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

/etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1       test-dev.com 

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.test-dev.com
        ServerAlias test-dev.com

        DocumentRoot "/home/xyz/Desktop/test/wordpress/"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

I never had any issue serving the pages outside /var/www/. But my old machine just died so I have to migrate to a new machine.
What have I missed? I tried all the answers I found online but non of them work, for example:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/xyz/Desktop/test

Any ideas?

That's normal. www-data needs to have read access to ALL directories in the tree. It's an insecure practice to give www-data read/traverse access to /home/ and its subdirectories, and you should instead create the directory for the web root in /var/www/ in a subdirectory or similar and then chown that directory to be owned by you.

This could also be the result of apparmor preventing Apache from reading outside of /var/www. This can be tested by checking to see if the service is running and, if it is, temporarily stopping it so that you can test access to the requisite directories. If it’s an AppArmor limitation, then you can add the requisite source directories to the AppArmor profile and everything will work as it should

@matigo yes it is running. how do I  add the requisite source directories to the AppArmor profile?

Set Permissions
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/xyz/Desktop/test

And restart apache using this command
sudo systemctl restart apache2

Or add the user to the www-data group, use the next
sudo usermod -a -G www-data username

After adding the user to the group
You can do this by adjusting the group ownership and permissions.
sudo chown -R :www-data /home/xyz/Desktop/test
sudo chmod -R 750 /home/xyz/Desktop/test


IMHO, chmod is sort of "bad practice". The better option here, is to add the user to the group www-data. The server should be able to read the directory then, without changing any read:write permissions in the folder. Plus no other users on the server (if there are any) can read my home folder, which might have sensitive information.

I did add the user to the www-data group. check the updates.

thanks for the answer. but still, it doesn't work...:-(
